# How can I calculate Average of Moving Average points in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

can you please help me with this?
I want to find the average of the points that are plotted by simple moving average. How can I do find this?
please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
len = input.int(30, title = "length")

ma = ta.sma(close, len)
var float ma_sum = 0
var float n = 0

if not na(ma)
    ma_sum += ma
    n += 1

avg = ma_sum / n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
len = input.int(30, title = "length")
len2 = input.int(5, title = "length_smooth")

ma = ta.sma(close, len)
avg = ta.wma(ma, len2)
```

This is leaner code. wma has less lag than sma,if that's needed